# Javascript form with calculation of three related variables

Tags: javascript, selectedindex, parsefloat

basically I'm trying to do something that is really easy in a spreadsheet but very complicated (at least for me) in a web page.

So, I have 11 book sizes, each one can have between 24 and 160 pages, and the the page cost varies on the book size (3 different costs). I need to come out with a total price for a book after the user selected the dropdown options.

This as far as I got, if anyone can help, I'd be much obliged!

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title><!--Sample--></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- BEGIN HIDING
    document.onchange = function( e )
    { e = e ? e : window.event;
      t = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
      if (( t.name ) && ( t.name == 'paginas' )) 
    { var thisPhotobook = product.photobook;
      var thisPrice = product.price;
      var thisPaginas = product.paginas;
      var thisTotal = product.total;
      thisTotal.value = '$' + t.selectedIndex * parseFloat (thisPrice.value); }
    }
    // DONE HIDING --> 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <br />
    <form name="product" action="#" onsubmit="return false;"> 
    <tr align="left">    
    <td width="118">
    <span class="style3">Photobooks</span>     
    <select name="photobook" size="1">     
    <option value="129">Pequeño tapa blanda (A5) </option>
    <option value="199">Pequeño tapa dura (A5) </option>
    <option value="189">Clásico vertical tapa blanda (A4) </option>
    <option value="255">Clásico horizontal tapa dura (A4) </option>
    <option value="255">Clásico vertical tapa dura (A4) </option>
    <option value="189">Cuadrado tapa blanda </option>
    <option value="255">Cuadrado tapa dura </option>
    <option value="329">Premium </option>
    <option value="329">Premium tapa tela </option>
    <option value="349">Super Premium (A3) </option>    
    <option value="349">Super Premium tapa tela (A3) </option>    
    </select>     
    <span class="style3">Páginas</span>     
    <select name="paginas" size="1">     
    <option>0 </option>
    <option value="2">24 </option>
    <option value="4">26 </option>
    <option value="6">28 </option>
    <option value="8">30 </option>
    <option value="10">32 </option>
    <option value="12">34 </option>
    <option value="14">36 </option>
    <option value="16">38 </option>
    <option value="18">40 </option>
    <option value="20">42 </option>
    <option value="22">44 </option>
    <option value="24">46 </option>
    <option value="26">48 </option>
    <option value="28">50 </option>
    <option value="30">52 </option>
    <option value="32">54 </option>
    <option value="34">56 </option>
    <option value="36">58 </option>
    <option value="38">60 </option>
    <option value="40">62 </option>
    <option value="42">64 </option>
    <option value="44">66 </option>
    <option value="46">68 </option>
    <option value="48">70 </option>
    <option value="50">72 </option>
    <option value="52">74 </option>
    <option value="54">76 </option>
    <option value="56">78 </option>
    <option value="58">80 </option>
    <option value="60">82 </option>
    <option value="62">84 </option>
    <option value="64">86 </option>
    <option value="66">88 </option>
    <option value="68">90 </option>
    <option value="70">92 </option>
    <option value="72">94 </option>
    <option value="74">96 </option>
    <option value="76">98 </option>
    <option value="78">100 </option>
    <option value="80">102 </option>
    <option value="82">104 </option>
    <option value="84">106 </option>
    <option value="86">108 </option>
    <option value="88">110 </option>
    <option value="90">112 </option>
    <option value="92">114 </option>
    <option value="94">116 </option>
    <option value="96">118 </option>
    <option value="98">120 </option>
    <option value="100">122 </option>
    <option value="102">124 </option>
    <option value="104">126 </option>
    <option value="106">128 </option>
    <option value="108">130 </option>
    <option value="110">132 </option>
    <option value="112">134 </option>
    <option value="114">136 </option>
    <option value="116">138 </option>
    <option value="118">140 </option>
    <option value="120">142 </option>
    <option value="122">144 </option>
    <option value="124">146 </option>
    <option value="126">148 </option>
    <option value="128">150 </option>
    <option value="130">152 </option>
    <option value="132">154 </option>
    <option value="134">156 </option>
    <option value="136">158 </option>
    <option value="138">160 </option>
    </select>     
    <span class="style3">Precio por página</span>     
    <select name="price" >
      <option value="2">2 </option>
      <option value="2,5">2,5 </option>
      <option value="5">5 </option>
    </select>

    &nbsp;<input name="total" type="text" value="0" size="5" style="text-align: center;" />
    </td> 
    </tr> 
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeleton which you can update with your calculation: [Javascript form with calculation](http://jsbin.com/imuGIpI/1/edit?html,js,output)

The only change I made to the HTML was to add the `id` attribute to your form elements (3 selects and 1 input). The `id` attribute is the modern way of accessing a particular element on a page instead of using `name`.

As far as `parseFloat`, I changed the `value` attribute of the `price` dropdown to use US style floating points (period, not a comma) (Pardon my ignorance of what other countries besides the US use a period.)

This syntax is used to access a particular element and get its value (`value` attribute):

```
var priceEl = document.getElementById('price');
price = priceEl.value;
```

This syntax is used to add an event handler. For each of the three selects, we say that when the `change` event fires, to run the `updatePrice` function.

```
priceEl.addEventListener('change', updatePrice, false);
```